# PhpStorm: break on errors when running PHPUnit tests

Tags: debugging, phpunit, phpstorm

PHPUnit tests are designed to swallow errors and exceptions and just print them to the console which is a correct default behavior. However, if I wanted PhpStorm to break on errors (not failures) in tests, is there a way to configure it that way?

Ideally, I'd like to do:

1. Turn on the magic switch I'm asking about.
2. Debug the unit tests.
3. Watch PhpStorm break when an error occurs.

Comment: Well ... the best I can think of is: 1) https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.2/debugging-in-the-just-in-time-mode.html?search=just 2) https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2013/12/just-in-time-debugging-and-php-exception-breakpoints-with-phpstorm-and-xdebug/